# Считается ли это уточнением?

Tags: пунктуация

В 2015 году, в рамках программы импортозамещения, совместно с итальянским производителем пневмоприводной техники на территории РФ открыта российско-итальянская компания...

Comment: Я бы вообще не выделял запятыми - и год, и программа, и совместность - все описывают независимые понятия: обстоятельство времени, обстоятельство места, обстоятельство образа действия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Само по себе - не считается (в строгом смысле, "рамки мероприятия" - понятие вневременное и не может "уточнять" год), но многое зависит от контекста и автора. Если перед этим долго рассказывалось, напр. что "2015 год стал для нас поворотной вехой в отношении к импорту", то приданием обороту статуса уточняющего (выделением его запятыми) можно акцентировать этот оборот как уточняющее напоминание об уже заявленной особенности этого года (мол, важен этот год тем, о чём мы говорили, и чего до него не было). Если такой нестандартный акцент не нужен (или для него нет оснований), то без запятых можно (или нужно) обойтись. Подобные примеры трансформации оборота во временную область (привязки к упомянутому перед ним моменту) есть у Лопатина: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=220

Comment: Как правило, при строгом уточнении мы можем задать вопрос _Как именно?_ или _Где именно?_. Но, как я понимаю, уточняющий оборот может возникнуть из условий контекста... Наверное, это можно считать запятыми, облегчающими восприятие текста. Спасибо.